# How to make progress bar with dotted lines?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, progress-bar

Maybe you've already seen such a progress bar? Share links for example. Are there any ideas how to do it? Thank you!
[Image progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6np4.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's this amazing library called ProgressBar.js - https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that canvas is not the best solution...

You can easy create this with SVG:

Some Lines as an sample, modify it to solve your problem:

```
      var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
      svg.setAttribute('width', '200');
      svg.setAttribute('height', '200');
      svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 200 200"); 
      svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

    var myLine=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
      with(myLine){
        setAttribute("x1", "100");
        setAttribute("y1", "5");
        setAttribute("x2", "100");
        setAttribute("y2", "15");
        setAttribute("stroke", "#ccc");
        setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
        setAttribute("transform", "rotate(0,100,100)");

      }
    var myNodes=[];
    var els=100;
    var step = 360/els;
    for (var i=0;i<els;i++){
      myNodes[i]=myLine.cloneNode(true);
      myNodes[i].setAttribute("transform", "rotate("+i*step+",100,100)");
      svg.appendChild(myNodes[i]);
    }

    //make 30% red;
    var percent=30;
    for (i=0;i<=percent;i++){
      myNodes[i].setAttribute("stroke", "#f00");
    }
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
```

see a liddle [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cd9vhfbs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple progress bar you can use HTML5's `<progress>` element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress)  which seems to be supported quite well: http://caniuse.com/#feat=progress

You could then apply custom style on it so that you can see little dots when the progress increases.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 Canvas API is a great pure JS solution for this type of thing.

Check this out - https://codepen.io/JanAmbrozic/pen/ZpVvXN

```
var progressCircle = {
  init: function(width, height, lineWidth, color) {
    var el = document.getElementById('progressCircle');    
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('progCanvas');
    this.span = document.getElementById('progSpan');
    this.span.textContent = '0%';    
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.canvas.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = height;
    this.ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    this.ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    this.ctx.rotate(-90*Math.PI/180);    
    this.radius = (width - lineWidth) / 2;
    this.drawCircle("#edc79b", 100);
  },

  drawCircle : function(color, percent) {    
        percent = percent/100;
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(0, 0, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2 * percent, false);
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```